# Powershell: Cannot convert the "System.Collections.Hashtable" value of type "System.Collections.Hashtable" to type "System.Uri"

Tags: powershell

Goal: I want to send a POST API request to JIRA with irm (Invoke-RestMethod).

Environment:

- OS: Windows 10 64 bit
- Powershell 5 (I think it's 5, it's the default that comes with Windows)

Script:

```
$Body = @{
    'fields' = @{
       'project' = @{'key' = 'ABC'}
       'summary' = "summary"
       'description' =  "desc"
       'issuetype' = @{'name' = 'Test'}
       'assignee' = 'user'
   }
}

$JsonBody = ($Body | ConvertTo-Json)

$params = @{
    Uri         = "https://jira.myjira.co.uk/rest/api/latest/issue"
    Headers     = @{ "Authorization" = "Basic myToken" }
    Method      = "POST"
    Body        = $JsonBody
    ContentType = "application/json"
}

$response = irm $params
$response | Out-File test.txt
```

When I execute it, I get the message below. Powershell is complaining but I don't know what is wrong with my parameters.

```
Invoke-RestMethod : Cannot bind parameter 'Uri'. Cannot convert the "System.Collections.Hashtable" value of type
"System.Collections.Hashtable" to type "System.Uri".
At C:\Users\User\Downloads\MyScript.ps1:64 char:17
+ $response = irm $params
+                 ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

What I've tried:

- Executed it in ISE and it does the same thing
- I used the @params format for another script and it was fine. I wonder if the issue is with the Uri part...
- Googling and looking at stackoverflow, there was similar matches but doesn't fit my scenario

Any help is appreciated, I've been banging my head against a wall for an hour.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply change the $params to @params, this is called splatting.

"Splatting is a method of passing a collection of parameter values to a command as a unit."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.1

```
$response = irm @params
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried changing the script so many times and the answer was a simple one character change!